# What is the reason to not use s after a countable noun?

Tags: grammar, singular

I'm questioning about this sentence below:

> How do you make this machine work?

I took that sentence from my exercise book. So, why didn't they put "s" after "work". Isn't *this machine* countable? I've made it sure it's countable by looking up on my dictionary. Hope you want to explain in detail. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In English, the verbs “make” and “let” are followed by an object and the infinitive without “to”, for example:

- They can't **make** you **work** late.
- She **made** him **do** the exercise again.
- How do you **make** this machine **work**?

In each of the examples above, you will notice a form of the verb *make* in bold, followed by an object (i.e., "you," "him," and "this machine," respectively) and then the infinitive form of a verb without "to" in bold (i.e., "work," "do," and "work," respectively).

For further explanation, see the following reference:

https://www.english-at-home.com/grammar/make-and-let/